# Using JSTL c:choose for condition based on URL

Tags: jstl, parameter-passing, el

So, bear in my I've never used JSTL before today.

What I'm trying to do is basically say if the URL = "www.website.com/urlone", then display a specific block of HTML code. Otherwise, display the regular code.

Am I on the right track?

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${param.enter=='1'}">
    DISPLAY ALTERNATE LOGO
</c:when>    
<c:otherwise>
    DISPLAY MAIN LOGO
</c:otherwise>
```

Obviously, I'm just not sure what function to use in the 'test' field.

Answer (score 1):

You thus want to extract information from the HTTP request URL. In EL, the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) instance is available by [`${pageContext.request}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#getRequest--). This class has in turn several methods which could be of use, such as [`getContextPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath--), [`getRequestURI()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI--) or even [`getRequestURL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL--).

Given a page which is opened on `http://www.website.com/urlone`, it isn't exactly clear if the context path is root or not. If it isn't and the webapp is deployed to a context path of `/urlone`, then you could use below check:

```
<c:when test="${pageContext.request.contextPath eq '/urlone'}">
    DISPLAY ALTERNATE LOGO
</c:when>
```

Or if it's actually deployed to root, and the `/urlone` thus actually represents the URI (matching your servlet or JSP), then do so:

```
<c:when test="${pageContext.request.requestURI eq '/urlone'}">
    DISPLAY ALTERNATE LOGO
</c:when>
```

If the resource is indeed served by a servlet, then the [`getServletPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath--) is also a possibility if the URL can have path parameters such as `/urlone/foo/bar` which you'd like to ignore (i.e. when you mapped the servlet to an URL pattern of `/urlone/*` instead of `/urlone`).

```
<c:when test="${pageContext.request.servletPath eq '/urlone'}">
    DISPLAY ALTERNATE LOGO
</c:when>
```

Or if you prefer checking the entire URL, which is not really maintenance friendly as the scheme, domain and port are fully outside control of the webapp, but alas:

```
<c:when test="${pageContext.request.requestURL eq 'http://www.website.com/urlone'}">
    DISPLAY ALTERNATE LOGO
</c:when>
```